# Mapping action through wildcard method in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am getting `NoSuchMethodException` while mapping my action using `Wildcard method` in `Struts2`.My app works fine If I create a separate action but I get an error while mapping it through `Wildcard` method.

Form

```
<form name="viewIntegrationReport" id="viewIntegrationReport" action="  <integration:urlAction actionName='/integration/ReportIntegration'> </integration:urlAction>" method="POST"></form>
```

Separate Action

```
 <action name="viewReportIntegration" method="viewTransactionReport" class="com.integration.webapp.action.IntegrationAction">
        <result name="integrationDetailsReportResponse" type="tiles">integrationReportView</result>
    </action>
```

Using `Wildcard`

```
<action name="*Integration" method="{1}" class="com.integration.webapp.action.IntegrationAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">integrationView</result> 
        <result name="integrationDetailsReportResponse" type="tiles">integrationReportView</result>
</action>
```

I am not certain what I am doing wrong in here.

Comment: Which S2 version? What url produces `<integration:urlAction>` tag? Post the stacktrace.

Comment: integration:urlAction ? o.O

Comment: Thank you Roman for the response but I just got it. The method name in my java class was not following the wildcard pattern.

Comment: I think the better option is to answer this question so that beginners can learn instead of deleting it.

Comment: You could get rid of custom tag and use `s:url`, if you are curious about mapping try actions with slashes in action name and/or configure your own action mapper, or use actions by convention.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it is better to answer this question rather than deleting it. It may help someone who knows.

I was getting `NoSuchMethodException` and the reason was that the name of the method in my `java class` wasn't matching the pattern I defined in my `action`.

action

```
*Integration
```

action method name in .java file

```
Changed it from viewTransactionReport to viewReport
```